# Ticks position in heatmap with categorical data (seaborn)

Tags: matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn, heatmap

I am trying to plot a confusion matrix of my predictions. My data is multi-class (13 different labels) so I'm using a heatmap.

As you can see below, my heat map looks generally okay but the labels are a bit out of position: y ticks should be a little lower and x ticks should be a bit more to the right. I want to move both axis ticks a bit so they will aligned with the center of each square.

[image: My Confusion Matrix]

my code:

```py
sns.set()
my_mask = np.zeros((con_matrix.shape[0], con_matrix.shape[0]), dtype=int)
for i in range(con_matrix.shape[0]):
    for j in range(con_matrix.shape[0]):
        my_mask[i][j] = con_matrix[i][j] == 0 

fig_dims = (10, 10)
plt.subplots(figsize=fig_dims)
ax = sns.heatmap(con_matrix, annot=True, fmt="d", linewidths=.5, cmap="Pastel1", cbar=False, mask=my_mask, vmax=15)
plt.xticks(range(len(party_names)), party_names, rotation=45)
plt.yticks(range(len(party_names)), party_names, rotation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

and for reproduction purpose, here are `con_matrix` and `party_names` hard-coded:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns 

con_matrix = np.array([[55, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,2], [0,199,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1],
 [0, 0,52,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
 [0,0,0,39,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,90,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,3],
 [0,0,0,1,0,35,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,5,0,26,0,0,1,0,1,0],
 [0,5,0,0,0,1,0,44,0,0,3,0,1],
 [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,52,0,0,0,0],
 [0,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,235,0,1,1],
 [1,2,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,34,0,3],
 [0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,1,0,40,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,46]])

party_names = ['Blues', 'Browns', 'Greens', 'Greys', 'Khakis', 'Oranges', 'Pinks', 'Purples', 'Reds', 'Turquoises', 'Violets', 'Whites', 'Yellows']
```

I already tried to work with `position` argument of different axes, but it did not turn out well. Could not find an exactly answer in this site as well (at least not a solution that works for categorical data).

I'm new in visualization with seaborn, any improvement with explanations would be appreciated (not only for my problem but on my code & visualization as well).

Comment: Just use `plt.xticks(np.arange(0.5, len(party_names)), ...` and similar for y. That way the ticks are positioned nicely in the center of each cell.

Comment: Note that you also can add the ticklabels directly: `ax = sns.heatmap(..., xticklabels=party_names, yticklabels=party_names)`. You can still rotate them using `plt.xticks(rotation=45)` without extra parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shift both the ticklabels by 0.5 offset to have the desired alignment. To do so, I have used NumPy's `arange` that enables vectorized addition of 0.5 to the whole array.

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(party_names))+0.5, party_names, rotation=45)
plt.yticks(np.arange(len(party_names))+0.5, party_names, rotation='horizontal')
```

[image]